# Double array Strings interconnect in output - C Programming

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char p[5][5];
    int i,j;

    for(i=1;i<=1;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=2;j++) {
            printf("\nInput Product code %d of day %d: ", j,i);
            scanf("%s", &p[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(i=1;i<=1;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=2;j++) {
            printf("\n\tProduct code %s day %d", &p[i][j],i);
        }
    }

}
```

This code outputs:

```
Input Product code 1 of day 1: hello

Input Product code 2 of day 1: hi

  Product code hhi day 1

Product code hi day 1
```

Does anyone know why hello and hi are interconnecting instead of printing hello in the first one?

I have researched a lot on strings but none seem to work better than this one.

Comment: `for(i=1;i<=1;i++)` seems a wee bit pointless to me...

Comment: yep..making sure it works the first time, wouldn’t want to waste any of my precious time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p[][]` is not a double array of strings but a double array of chars.  It has 5 rows and 5 columns like this:

```
p[row][column] = 

 Row| Column ->         |
  v | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 0 |   |   |   |   |   |
| 1 |   |   |   |   |   |
| 2 |   |   |   |   |   |
| 3 |   |   |   |   |   |
| 4 |   |   |   |   |   |
```

The first `scanf()` is called when i = 1, j = 1 and copies the string "hello" leaving `p[][]` like this ('\0' is the NUL character that terminates strings):

```
    | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 0 |   |   |   |   |   |
| 1 |   | H | e | l | l |
| 2 | o |\0 |   |   |   |
| 3 |   |   |   |   |   |
| 4 |   |   |   |   |   |
```

The next time it is called, i = 1, j = 2:

```
    | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 0 |   |   |   |   |   |
| 1 |   | H | h | i |\0 |
| 2 | o |\0 |   |   |   |
| 3 |   |   |   |   |   |
| 4 |   |   |   |   |   |
```

One way you could write this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_CODE_LEN   80 /* or something */

int main(void) 
{
    char *code[5][5] = {0},
         currentCode[MAX_CODE_LEN] = {0};
    int day = 0,
        codeNum = 0;

    /* start loops at 0 */
    for ( day = 0; day < 5; day++ ) {

        for ( codeNum = 0; codeNum < 5; codeNum++ ) {
            int len = 0;

            printf("\nInput Product code %d of day %d: ", codeNum, day);
            scanf("%s", currentCode);

            /* len doesn't include NUL but malloc needs it */
            len = strlen(currentCode);

            /* yoda style so compiler catches assignment instead of equality */
            if ( 0 == len ) {
                /* if the user didn't enter a code move onto the next day */
                code[day][codeNum] = NULL;
                break;
            }
            len = len >= MAX_CODE_LEN? MAX_CODE_LEN - 1: len;
            code[day][codeNum] = malloc(len * sizeof(char) + 1);
            strcpy(code[day][codeNum], currentCode);
        }
    }

    for ( day = 0; day < 5; day++ ) {

        for ( codeNum = 0; codeNum < 5; codeNum++ ) {

            if ( NULL == code[day][codeNum] ) {
                /* no more codes for today */
                break;
            }
            printf("\n\tProduct code %s day %d", code[day][codeNum], day);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char p[5][5];
```

this is a matrix of charachters and not matrix of strings

and with your `scanf()`, you want to put for each element in the matrix a string. And this is impossible.

You have to use one of the following definition:

1)

```
char p[5][5][MAX_SIZE_OF_INPUT_STRINGS];
```

and the scanf should be

```
scanf("%s", p[i][j]);
```

2)

```
char *p[5][5];
```

and the scanf should be

```
scanf("%ms", p[i][j]);
```

`p[i][j]` here is pointed to a memory allocated dynamically by `scanf()` and you have to free it with `free(p[i][j])` when the `p[i][j]` become useless in your program

Comment: I think this is off-target.  There's no need to add a third dimension to the array to make the code work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because strings are just arrays of chars(terminated by `\0` or `null`.  Right now, you're indexing chars, and `scanf` is just taking the char reference you pass it, and filling the rest of the structure with it until it's done filling with the string.

what you're doing is setting p to

```
* * * * *
* h e l l
o\0 * * *
* * * * *
* * * * *
```

and then

```
* * * * *
* h h i\0
o\0 * * *
* * * * *
* * * * *
```

If I were you, I'd populate closer to something like this

```
char p[5][6];
int i,j;


for(i=0;i<2;i++)
{

    printf("\nInput Product code of day %d: ", i);
    scanf("%s", &p[i]);
}

for(i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    printf("%s\n", &p[i]);
}
```

Comment: It's not quite that simple: `p[1][0]` has no specific value; `p[1][1]` contains the `h` of `hello`; `p[1][2]` contains the `h` of `hi`, etc.  The entry of `hello` overruns the end of the sub-array `p[1]`, writing to `p[2][0]` and `p[2][1]`.  _However_, the suggested fix, including the extra space for the null, is about right.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler didn't take into account the indexing at 1 on the `j` variable